# In C, what is evaluated in compile time?

Tags: c

Can I set a variable to a certain value at compile time?

If I have a function that changes the value of all `struct`s at the program initialization, if I do it in compile time I save a lot of time and use of the processor, can I?

I learned that static and global variables initialize their values as `0`. If I declare like `static int a = 3;`, the number `3` will be assigned in compile or run time? If yes, it's true to compond literals too? How can I know if it is true? (I don't know how to use a debug for that.)

I learned about constant C expressions too, but I can't understand what this is. Will it be of any use to me? What is it?

UPDATE: I ONLY ASKING IF I CAN CHANGE A VALUE OF A VARIABLE IN COMPILE TIME!!! (and another some things...)

Comment: If you can't explain it, we can't answer it.

Comment: You said it because probably you stopped on 'i don't know how to explain it' , If you hold reading you would understand my citation.

Comment: Absolutely! If you initialize the structs at compile time, you will save *hundreds* of microseconds. Maybe *thousands!*

Answer (score 3):

*Some basic principles of optimization:*

- only optimize measured (profiled) bottlenecks, don't waste time optimizing imaginary or hypothetical issues, unless you are a subject-matter expert who is reimplementing a known compute-time issue
- don't optimize anything unless it's in a loop

But to answer your question...

*Always at compile time:*

- static initialization
- `#if` and other preprocessor macro expressions

*Usually at compile time:*

- Any expression involving only constants

Comment: An even simpler guide  to optimisation - "don't at all". In all my programming careeer I've never found the need to optimise anything.

Comment: Sorry but it is not a question about optimization principles I only want to know how do that. the optimization comes after.

Comment: @Neil: There's a wide spectrum open there.  I, for instance, am right at the other end; my job is all about optimisation!

Comment: @Oli Well, most of the last jobs I've had (trading servers) have needed to be performant.

Comment: @Neil: Then how is it possible that you've never needed to look at potential optimisations?

Comment: @Oli Because the code I write naturally is fast enough. I'm not talking about the current trend for very fast trading, BTW, just for quite fast trading :-) A couple of years ago I decided that IB's and me were not meant for each other.

Comment: @Neil: Ah.  In HPC there's no such thing as "fast enough"!

Comment: @Neil: Do you claim that it couldn't be made faster by optimisation? There are fields where the aim is for code to be *as fast as possible* -- there is no "fast enough" (that is, you make the code as fast as you can and that determines the data rate you can cope with -- rather than having a predefined data rate and then only having to make the code fast enough to cope with that rate)

Comment: @Oli But there is something like "self respect".

Comment: @John No, I claim those fields are few and far between.

Comment: @Neil: I dunno -- games, video editing and image processing seem pretty popular to me. Higher performance in games means you can afford to have higher resolution artwork, more enemies, etc. Higher performance in video and image editing means you can cope with higher resolutions (this is a soft limit -- some users are willing to let the computer chug for longer to encode their video -- but it is a limit). There are plenty of domains in which well structured code with no special effort in optimisation *is* fast enough. But I think there are also plenty where we haven't reached that point.

Comment: @John The vast number of computer programs out there are not performance sensitive. As I said, I've never come across an instance where optimisation helps. But I'm not  a games programmer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you're curious about which kinds of variables get placed into which kinds of [data segments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment).

Uninitialized global variables and function-level `static` variables go into the `bss` section, which is really just a number in the object file telling the linker/loader how much space to set aside for the section when loading the program or library:

```
$ readelf --sections /bin/sh
There are 28 section headers, starting at offset 0x195e8:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type             Address           Offset
       Size              EntSize          Flags  Link  Info  Align
...
  [26] .bss              NOBITS           0000000000619500  00019500
       0000000000002bd0  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     32
```

That's 0x2bd0 == 11216 bytes to be set aside at runtime for uninitialized variables.

Global variables that are initialized are stored into the `data` or `rodata` section:

```
$ readelf --sections /bin/sh
There are 28 section headers, starting at offset 0x195e8:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type             Address           Offset
       Size              EntSize          Flags  Link  Info  Align
...
  [16] .rodata           PROGBITS         0000000000412de0  00012de0
       0000000000003482  0000000000000000   A       0     0     32
...
  [25] .data             PROGBITS         0000000000619300  00019300
       0000000000000200  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     32
```

Sorry, I've forgotten the exact rules the compiler / linker use to decide which variables go into the read only section and which variables go into the read / write section. But suffice to say that the linker will set the page protections to *read only* for the `rodata` section, and attempts to write to this section will generate a page fault and probably terminate the program.

```
char *string = "hello world"; /* "hello world\0" goes into rodata
                                 char *string goes into data */
```

I would expect any computation based solely on literal integers, floating point, and `sizeof()` operations to be computed at compile-time.

A very small example:

```
$ cat test.c
int i;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    return 0;
}
$ gcc -o test test.c
$ size test
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   1044     496      24    1564     61c test
```

The C library brings along a *lot* of extra baggage. But notice what happens when we initialize `i`, the `bss` size goes down, the `data` size goes up:

```
$ cat test.c
int i=1+2;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    return 0;
}
$ gcc -o test test.c
$ size test
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   1044     500      16    1560     618 test
$
```

I assume the `bss` is constrained to a multiple of `8` on my system, because it is an AMD64-compliant CPU. Other systems might require a multiple of `4`.

```
$ cat test.c
int i=sizeof(int);
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    return 0;
}
$ gcc -o test test.c
$ size test
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   1044     500      16    1560     618 test
$
```

Note that switching to `sizeof(int)` didn't increase the `text` (executable code) size, and didn't change the `data` size either.